# aura:id in sObjectLookup - aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura, lookup, aura-attribute

This is a code snippet of my aura component where i used sObjectLookup -

```
                <c:sObjectLookup fieldLabel = "Contact" objectAPIName = "Contact"
                fieldAPIName = "Name" subHeadingFieldsAPI = "Email,Phone"
                lookupIcon = "standard:contact" placeholder = "Search Contact"/>
```

but this is not supporting aura:id="" in it , why so? Is there anything i can use instead of aura:id inside sObjectLookup ??